TTL pulses through the Parallel port
i am trying to send pulses of the X axis through the PIN 1 DO, the Direction of the X axis of the Step Motor  through PIN 2 (D1), and the same for y axis through the PIN 3 D2, and the Direction of Y through the PIN 4 (D3) of a DB25 pins. How do i send them all at the same time?
I wrote this in example.c, compile it with gcc, but it doesnt work
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/io.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BASEPORT 0x378

int main(){
if(ioperm(BASEPORT,3,1))
{perror("ioperm");
return 1;
}

outb(0x01, BASEPORT);
outb(0x02, BASEPORT);
outb(0x03, BASEPORT);
outb(0x04, BASEPORT);
usleep(1000000);

outb(0x00, BASEPORT);
if(ioperm(BASEPORT,3,0))
{perror("ioperm");
return 1;
}

return 0;

}

Thanks a lot
Send TTL pulses to two DM420A steppmotors drivers.
